# Is it appropriate to use vlookup in this scenario

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

So I have an Excel table that looks like this:

```
Name Category Value
Joe  A
Joe  B        
Joe  C        4.2
Joe  D        3.22
Brad A        
Brad B        
Brad C        2.25
Brad D        4.1
Ryan A
Ryan B
Ryan C        1.22
Ryan D        5.22
```

Now, I want it to look like this:

```
Name Category Value
Joe  A        4.2
Joe  B        4.2
Joe  C        4.2
Joe  D        3.22
Brad A        2.25
Brad B        2.25
Brad C        2.25
Brad D        4.1
Ryan A        1.22
Ryan B        1.22
Ryan C        1.22
Ryan D        5.22
```

I was thinking of using an if statement combined with a vlookup (something like =if(isblank([value cell]),vlookup([name and category cell combination], [all columns in table], 3, false),[value cell]), but vlookup doesn't seem to accept multiple criteria. Is there a way to get the syntax to work here, or should I use a different function to do the job?

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: It's Excel 2010.

Comment: Check my answers and let us know your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If you user of ***Microsoft-365*** then could try-

```
=BYROW(C2:C13,
LAMBDA(x,
LET(tmp,x:INDEX(C2:C13,12),
INDEX(FILTER(tmp,tmp<>""),1)
)))
```

[image]

Comment: Works for this specific table, but not for really large datasets. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

For Excel-2010 try the following array formula-

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$13,MIN(IF($C2:$C$13<>"",ROW($C2:$C$13),""))-ROW($C$1))
```

Array formula means you must enter the formula by pressing `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

[image]